# add instructions to upload pages and / or forms

Tags: admin, uploads, metabox

I want to put file prep instruction on the media upload forms/pages/tabs.

There are a lot of people using the admin. There is a CMS guide but it is rarely read causing issues with page load slow downs as they're using any image format at any size.

They do need to use all image file types so banning PNGs, PDFs isn't possible. Large sizes need to be used in several places, so I can't use plugins to downsize files or stop large uploads.

Is it possible to add meta boxes or text instructions to these pages?

I can see its possible elsewhere ie -

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'register_my_dashboard_widget' );
```

Comment: Sure it's possible.

Comment: Would you be open to using the Contextual Help API? Using this, you'd be able to add documentation to the Help tab in the upper corner of the screen.

Comment: Anything that doesn't require hacking into Wordpress install and i can manage via plugin or form functions.php
I've wanted to do tis for years on several projects but never seem to find a decent solution.